# QGIS crashes when trying to display features form MySQL

Tags: qgis, ogr, ogr2ogr, mysql

I import shapefiles into MySQL using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:GIS,host=localhost,user=root,password=root /home/user/Public/myshape.shp -nln Shape_table -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM***
```

but the problem is that when I try to display features directly from MySQL in QGIS, QGIS crashes.

This is the crash message:

```
QGIS died on signal 11[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xa63ffb40 (LWP 12279)]
[New Thread 0xae910b40 (LWP 12237)]
[New Thread 0xaf239b40 (LWP 12236)]
0xb3dabf96 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0xafb5ab00 (LWP 12234))]
#0  0xb3dabf96 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
No symbol table info available.
#1  0xb3e89035 in QImage::fill(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
No symbol table info available.
```

...

Comment: Have you checked the QGIS bug tracker?